# SQL Query doesn't work in newer MySQL version

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that works fine on MySQL 5.0.45 and returns 4 rows, but returns no rows on MySQ 5.5.37.

**Query:**

```
SELECT id, MATCH (name, fb_title, fb_desc) AGAINST ('ic3') as score
FROM (`pages`)
WHERE `published` =  1
AND MATCH (name, fb_title, fb_desc) AGAINST ('ic3')
AND `section_id` IN (9, 1, 2, 3, 118, 8, 375, 119, 378, 120, 121, 320, 321, 4, 5, 6, 7, 204, 179, 205, 178) 
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

I feel it could be to do with MATCH, but I'm unsure.

Thanks

Comment: Check the syntax to make sure 5.5 supports them. Any error messages?

Comment: Could you pls provide us with an error message?

Comment: @Shadow Yeah, that's the annoying thing, it's not showing any errors, just returning 0 rows despite the data being identical on both servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the string 'ic3', which is 3 characters long. The default value for minimum fulltext word search is [4 in mysql v5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len). You should change this value to 3 **and** rebuild all fulltext indexes.

Comment: Ah Thanks, that makes sense